# CONSULTA ASP.Net Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

estoy empezando a usar ASP.Net Core 2.0 y en medio de este proceso estoy haciendo un mini proyecto de inventario, ya logro hacer entradas al inventario, los controladores los hice con el scaffolding, tengo mi clase "inventario" y mi clase "ventas", mi inquietud es la siguiente: 
No sé cómo al momento de registrar una venta en mi vista AgregarVenta también se modifique en mi base de datos, la tabla inventario restando la cantidad de ese producto que vendí, para que cuando vaya a mi vista de inventario y se encuentre actualizada cada que venda un producto.

No sé de qué forma modificar los controladores que genera Visual Studio al hacer el scaffolding por lo que vengo a ustedes.

Básicamente, tengo un objeto venta el cual estoy tratando, con su propiedad "cantidad" y quiero esa cantidad restarla a mi objeto en "inventario" que también tiene una cantidad.
Cabe mencionar que al momento de realizar mi venta tengo una relación con mi tabla inventario, es decir, para cada venta elijo el producto que quiero vender, pero no he hecho la lógica para descontar esa cantidad del inventario.

Disculpen mi forma de explicar, estoy tratando al 100% y estoy empezando en esto, muchas gracias

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("VentasId,FechaCompra,Cantidad,TotalVenta,ProductoId,ClienteId")] Ventas ventas)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(ventas);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["ClienteId"] = new SelectList(_context.Cliente, "ClienteId", "Direccion", ventas.ClienteId);
        ViewData["ProductoId"] = new SelectList(_context.Producto, "ProductoId", "ReferenciaFabrica", ventas.ProductoId);
        return View(ventas);
    }
```

MI MODELO INVENTARIO:

```
public class Inventario
{
    [Required]
    public int InventarioID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaInventario { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StockMinimo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StockMaximo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "{0} debe tener una longitud de {1} caracteres.")]
    public string Ubicacion { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaSalida { get; set; }

    public int ProductoId { get; set; }
    public Producto Producto { get; set; }

}
```

MI MODELO VENTAS:

```
public class Inventario
{
    [Required]
    public int InventarioID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaInventario { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StockMinimo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StockMaximo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "{0} debe tener una longitud de {1} caracteres.")]
    public string Ubicacion { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaSalida { get; set; }

    public int ProductoId { get; set; }
    public Producto Producto { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: coloca el codigo que tienes hasta el momento

Comment: Acabo de colocar el código de mi función Create, del controlador de ventas, creo que ahí debería ir la lógica de "Cuando se cree una venta, modificar el ObjInventario", también agregué mis modelos Inventario y Ventas

Comment: Podrías agregar tu vista también, por favor :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deberias obtener el inventario y actualizar su cantidad
a modo de ejemplo seria algo asi

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(ventas);

        var inventario = _context.Inventario.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductoId == ventas.ProductoId);

        if (inventario != null)
            inventario.cantidad -= ventas.cantidad;

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

el `SaveChanges()` se encarga de realizar el alta y la modificacion

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS WFgo, me ayudaste un montón y este ejercicio me ayudó a entender algunas cosas, de verdad muchas gracias!!!